# React (Next.js) hook useOutsideClick cancels my links

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, bulma

i'm using the following hook to handle "click away" feature to show/hide a dropdown:

```
const useOutsideClick = (ref: NonNullable<RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>>) => {
  const [outsideClick, setOutsideClick] = useState<boolean | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (e: React.MouseEvent | Event) => {
      if (
        ref &&
        !(ref?.current as unknown as RequiredCurrentRef).contains(
          e?.target as Node
        )
      ) {
        setOutsideClick(true)
      } else {
        setOutsideClick(false)
      }

      setOutsideClick(null)
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside)
    }
  }, [ref])

  return outsideClick
}
export default useOutsideClick
```

the hook works fine but once i click on `<a href>` links (separated component from the dropdown) it does not redirect, so links don't work
how do i solve this?

**Edit** i'm using [bulma.css](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/dropdown/) for dropdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont need to create an extra hook at all.

If you want do du something if the user clicks on or out of the element you can use the [onBlur](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onblur) and [onFocus](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#onfocus) callbacks.

If you want to blur it for some other reason (like on the click of a button) you can use the [reference of the anchor](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) and call the `blur()` method whenever you like.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm not using inputs for dropdowns, i use bulma.css

Comment: what element you are using doesn't really matter. The callbacks and ref API are available for every HTML element. 

If you provide a GitHub repo, or codesanbbox i can show you what I mean in code. :)

Comment: i just tried what you suggested, it works but if i handle the onBlur in the button that opens the dropown, and click the links provided in the dropdown it triggers the logic written in the onBlur and ends up closing the panel

Comment: i solved the problem by using onMouseDown instead of onClick in dropdown items and all works! thanks